# Why is my KNN algorithm built from scratch not working?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, knn

I tried creating a KNN algorithm from scratch. My dataset is a pandas DataFrame. The algorithm always returns a 1.0 (predictions always perfectly match the actual outcome) and I'm worried something is wrong, though I don't know what. Any help in identifying is much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
def get_neighbors(train,row,n):
      distances=list()
      for i in range(len(test)):
        dist=euclidean_distance(row,train.iloc[i])
        distances.append((row,dist))
      distances.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
      neighbors=list()
      for i in range(n):
        neighbors.append(distances[i][0])
      return neighbors

def predict_classification(train,row,n):
  neighbors=get_neighbors(train,row, n)
  output_values=[row.iloc[-1]for row in neighbors]
  prediction=max(set(output_values),key=output_values.count)
  return prediction
import math

def euclidean_distance(row1,row2):
  distance = 0.0
  for i in range((row1.shape[0])):
    distance+=(row1[i] -row2[i]) ** 2
  return math.sqrt(distance)

def k_nearest_neighbors(train,test,n):
  predictions=list()
  for i in range(len(test)):
    output=predict_classification(train,test.iloc[i],n)
    predictions.append(output)
  return(predictions)


train=dataset.iloc[0:500]
test=dataset.iloc[500:600]
df=po.DataFrame()
df["Actual"]=test["Outcome"]
df["Predicted"]=k_nearest_neighbors(train,test,5)
```

Comment: Are you sure your data shouldn't return 100% prediction. Some problems are just easy to solve!

Answer (score 0):

I havent't checked your code thoroughly but you have several issues here. Some of the are:

1. You are not using any labels. From your code one can suspect that the last column is  labels but then you shouldn't use them to calculate distances e.g. in here: `dist=euclidean_distance(row,train.iloc[i])`
2. You are appending the same sample here: `distances.append((row,dist))` not what you want. Append the row of the training set (not very efficient though)
3. Since you don't have any labels in here this is mess up: `output_values=[row.iloc[-1]for row in neighbors]`
4. Efficiency issues. Why are you working with pandas? Use numpy for your actual work and pass it to pandas when you're done.
5. You are using too many functions to do your classifications. Just iterate over your training data calculating distances. Get the indices (not the actual samples) of the detected `n` neighbors and after voting compare it with your ground truth. You don't need to save the actual samples somewhere (as you do).